# Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type error on JPA

Tags: jpa, jpql

I'm getting this error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [com.utc.pw.domain.evm.EVMQuestions]` when I'm trying to get results from database with this query

```
public List<EVMQuestions> getAllHeaders(String salesOrder,String module) {
        List<EVMQuestions> headers=null;
        if(salesOrder.contains("V")||salesOrder.contains("v"))
        {
            headers = entityManager.createQuery("select i.header,min(question_ID) from EVMQuestions i where i.engineType='V2500' AND i.module='"+module+"' group by header order by min(question_ID)", EVMQuestions.class).getResultList(); 
        }
        else
        {
            headers =  entityManager.createQuery("select DISTINCT i.header from EVMQuestions i where i.engineType='CFM56-7B' AND i.module='"+module+"'", EVMQuestions.class).getResultList(); 
        }
        for(EVMQuestions i : headers){
            i.getHeader();
            i.getQuestion_ID();
        }
        System.out.println("DB Connection Success - EVM Headers retrieved");
        return headers;
    }
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out the problem. I changed the code

```
public List<Object[]> getAllHeaders(String salesOrder,String module) {
        List<Object[]> headers=null;
        if(salesOrder.contains("V")||salesOrder.contains("v"))
        {
            headers = entityManager.createQuery("select i.header,min(question_ID) from EVMQuestions i where i.engineType='V2500' AND i.module='"+module+"' group by header order by min(question_ID)", Object[].class).getResultList(); 
        }
        else
        {
            headers =  entityManager.createQuery("select DISTINCT i.header from EVMQuestions i where i.engineType='CFM56-7B' AND i.module='"+module+"'", Object[].class).getResultList(); 
        }
        System.out.println("DB Connection Success - EVM Headers retrieved");
        return headers;
    }
```